# What is causing a light object on a table to move if the table is struck with a heavy object?

Tags: classical-mechanics, forces

When a light object is placed on a table and the table is struck with a heavy object causing the light object to shake on the table without the heavy object touching it, is it resonance or something else that is causing it to vibrate?

Answer (score 1):

By striking the table with a heavy object, you are causing vibrations (standing waves) of the table surface which, when strong enough, can impart sufficient impulse to the small object that it jumps off the surface.